# Pandas Iterating group by not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterator, drop-duplicates

I have a df with plenty of columns. Each row is basically like a train ticket. i have the valid_from and valid_to date and some informations about the train and route. There is a not unique key, that contains some information like the ticket provider and the start and end point. i grouped the whole df by the non unique key. now i have all tickets for a specific route by a specific provider in a group. Now I sort each group by the valid_from date and afterwards filter for duplicates in all columns except the valid_from and valid_to column. This gives me the actual contracts for train tickets without any duplicates. This is my code. my_col just contains all columns except the time columns.

```
grouped_df = network_dfs[0].groupby('route_key')
list_dfs_grouped = []

for name, group in grouped_df:
    group.sort_values('valid_from', ascending=True, inplace=True)
    dup_first = group.drop_duplicates(subset=my_col, keep="first")


    dup_last = group.drop_duplicates(subset=my_col, keep="last")

    dup_first.loc[:, 'valid_from'] = dup_last['valid_to']
    list_dfs_grouped.append(dup_first)


clean_df = pd.concat(list_dfs_grouped, axis=0, join='inner')
```

The problem is, that the code is not working as expected in some cases. the drop_duplicates sometimes doesnt identify duplicates, which results in duplicated entries beeing kept.

What is weird about this behavior is, that if I run the code below:

```
first_group = grouped_df.get_group('my_key')
first_group = first_group.sort_values('valid_from', ascending=True, inplace=True)
dup_first = first_group.drop_duplicates(subset=my_col, keep="first")

dup_last = first_group.drop_duplicates(subset=my_col, keep="last")
dup_first['valid_from'] = dup_last['valid_to']
```

The code works as expected and the same group gets reduced by all duplicates.
All columns have correct dtypes and I use the same grouped df in both cases.
When using the iterator in some cases drop_duplicates just returns too many values.

Any suggestions, what I can do to fix this behavior?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there! Please take a look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/15873043) and update your question accordingly by providing a minimal reproducible example that shows the behavior you describe. Without it it's very difficult to help since we don't know your data.

Comment: Because pandas aligns on index, I'd also be very careful in checking that `dup_first.loc[:, 'valid_from'] = dup_last['valid_to']` is doing what you think it's doing